# Socket.io receiving data from multiple sockets in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, npm, socket.io

I started developing in Node just a couple of days ago. I'm currently developing an online game that uses Node as server-side application. This application simply provides the .html and .js files to the client and handles the logic of the game.
I'm using Socket.io to exchange data with the clients. When a new client connects to the server through Socket.io the program looks for a room (array of objects containing the sockets for the two users and the game object that handles the logic) that has an empty space and places the user (registering the socket) in it. 
I've been able to correctly send to each client the position of the sprites, but I have a problem with retrieving data from each socket: If I try to send some data from the client to the server, that data flows through only one of the two sockets, no matter which client is sending that.

**Initializing the room array**

```
for(var i = 0; i < roomsNumber; i++) {
  //player1 and player 2 are going to store the sockets
  rooms[i] = { player1 : null, player2 : null, game: null};
}
```

**Socket.io handling the connections**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("We have a new client: " + socket.id);
  insertPlayer(socket);

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("Client has disconnected: " + socket.id);
    removePlayer(socket);
  });
});
```

**Adding the clients to rooms**

```
function insertPlayer(socket) { //Check for an empty spot in a room
  for(var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
    if(!rooms[i].player1) {
      rooms[i].player1 = socket; //Register the socket to the room
      checkRooms();
      return;
    }
    if(!rooms[i].player2) {
      rooms[i].player2 = socket; //Register the socket to the room
      checkRooms();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**Creating the Game object when a room if full (and destructing it when a player leaves)**

```
function checkRooms() { //Checks if a room is full to initialize the game
  for(var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
    if(rooms[i].player1 && rooms[i].player2 && !rooms[i].game) {
      rooms[i].game = new Game([rooms[i].player1, rooms[i].player2]); //The constructor passes the sockets
      console.log('New game started');
    }
    if((!rooms[i].player1 || !rooms[i].player2) && rooms[i].game) {
      rooms[i].game.endGame();
      rooms[i].game = null;
      console.log('Game stopped');
    }
  }
}
```

**Receiving data in the Game class**

```
constructor(sockets) {
  this.sockets = sockets;
  this.snakes = [];
  var self = this;

  for(var i = 0; i < this.sockets.length; i++) {
    this.snakes[i] = new Snake(i*100 + 100, 200);
    var currentSnake = this.snakes[i];
    var currentSocket = this.sockets[i];

  currentSocket.on('keyPressed', function(data) {
    currentSnake.updateDirection(data); //Calls a Game method that updates the direction of the sprite 
    console.log(currentSocket.id + " - " + data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think we can see enough code here to understand or see where the problem is.  For example, the only place in this code where you are receiving data from a client socket is in the Game class, but you don't show when you create a Game class and how you create the list of sockets it has.  If you create a Game with only two sockets in it initially, then that is all the sockets you will ever register to receive the `keyPressed` event on.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "that data flows through only one of the two sockets, no matter which client is sending that".  What exactly do you observe that causes you to say that?  And, what problem are you seeing?

Comment: The game for now consists in two snakes that move in the frame. Each snake is controlled by one user and every user can see both his snake and the enemy's. To make the direction of the snake change, the user has to press the arrow buttons (this sends some data to the server). When I try the game (across two tabs of the browser) I see the two snakes, and when I press the arrow key on the first tab the snake, let's say number 1, changes direction. When I change tab and I press the arrow button again the snake that changes direction is still snake number 1.

Comment: OK, my answer below (which was written before I saw your recent comment) should fix that exact issue.  In the future, please add that type of very good and detailed description of the problem to your question when you first post it and make sure you include all code relevant to that problem.  You will get answers much quicker.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I'll try to be more precise the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem with the `currentSnake` variable in your `Game` constructor.  That variable is scoped to your whole constructor so there's only one variable there, but you're trying to have a separate variable for each player and that isn't working.  Thus, every time you get the `keyPressed` message, you operation on the same snake, no matter which player the key came from.

If you're using node.js v6+, then change `var currentSnake` in that constructor to `let currentSnake` so that the variable is separately scoped to each invocation of the `for` loop.

```
constructor(sockets) {
  this.sockets = sockets;
  this.snakes = [];
  var self = this;

  for(var i = 0; i < this.sockets.length; i++) {
    this.snakes[i] = new Snake(i*100 + 100, 200);
    // change these to be declared with let so they are separately scoped 
    //   for each invocation of the for loop
    let currentSnake = this.snakes[i];
    let currentSocket = this.sockets[i];

    currentSocket.on('keyPressed', function(data) {
      currentSnake.updateDirection(data); //Calls a Game method that updates the direction of the sprite 
      console.log(currentSocket.id + " - " + data);
    });
  }
}
```

Or, if you are running an older version of node.js, switch to `.forEach()` to replace the `for` loop as this will also make a new separate scope for each invocation of the loop.

```
constructor(sockets) {
  this.sockets = sockets;
  this.snakes = [];
  var self = this;

  this.sockets.forEach(function(currentSocket, i) {
    this.snakes[i] = new Snake(i*100 + 100, 200);
    var currentSnake = this.snakes[i];

    currentSocket.on('keyPressed', function(data) {
      currentSnake.updateDirection(data); //Calls a Game method that updates the direction of the sprite 
      console.log(currentSocket.id + " - " + data);
    });
  });
}
```